# Intranet machines refuse to talk anymore

Tags: windows, networking

I have two machines on the local intranet. They used to be able to talk to each other (ping, share files, etc.). Both are not successfully connected to the internet.

The problem machine (lets call it `test` machine) can't talk to my main machine. The test machine can ping other machines on the intranet (at least one of my coworkers), but not mine.

Odd. When I try to ping it from my machine, by machine name, I get `Destination host unreachable.`

- Both machines are on the intranet, with the network configured as `Work`
- Both machines have Windows Firewall disabled temporarily
- Both machines can talk to the internet (Google, SO, etc.)
- Neither machine can ping the other

I need help resolving this. What I really want to achieve, is to remote into the test machine from my main machine, like I used to be able to do a few weeks ago.

Some notes:

- Tried `arp -a` on both machines. I don't see the other machine's IP listed.
- Both machines have stable IPs; neither seems to have an IP conflict
- The configuration under `ipconfig /all` on my main machine mathces my coworker's machine. The test machine can ping his machine, but not my machine.
- The target machine times out trying to ping the main machine; the main machine gives me `Destination host unreachable`.
- I have rebooted both machines (several times) to no avail
- I have `/release` and `/renew`ed both machines several times

Network topology:

- Plug in the wall has two ethernet ports: one for the VOIP phone and one for the PC's internet.
- The VOIP phone has an output for ethernet; it can funnel network requests to your PC.
- Main machine connects directly to the internet from the wall plug
- Test machine connects through the phone

Comment: How are they connected to each other? There could be settings on switches to prevent internal communication, different VLANs.

Comment: Would it be possible to add details of the networking and subnets?

Comment: I'm not sure how they're connected to each other via the office network. I have two ethernet cables: one goes to my main machine, the other to my test machine. From my end, they have no explicit connection. It's not possible to add networking/subnet details; but they are on the same subnet, with the same gateway.

Comment: So how do your machines connect, to a switch/hub/router or are the directly connected/ dual nics? Please update your question with the network topology. For example MachineA+cableA connects to machineB or MachineA+cableA = switch / machineB+ cableB = switch

Comment: @onxx I don't really know. I'll try to update it with whatever I do know.

Answer (score -1):

Buy a switch to connect your pcs together.

Comment: -1, please explain how this would enable the OP to solve his problem, diagnosis and steps required etc.